# How do I preserve websites' current URLs?

Tags: web, url, url-rewriting

How do you preserve URLs of your website once you get it transferred to a new platform (tbd), and hosting (tbd)?

Are 301 redirects the only way to do that?

Please forgive any lacking in the question as I'm trying to fill out the paper for my boss, and not sure what to recommend. Would super appreciate solutions to preserving the current URLs for website.

Let me know if I need to fill in additional information that would inform the answer. I'm writing in PST time. Thank you.

EDIT 1:

Would it help to list potential CMS you may move the site to?

Maybe Joomla? Any recommendations that are not either Drupal (way too advanced) or WordPress (way too easy to bloat and don't know how to "slim" it down once bloated) ...

Say your original URLs are like:

example one: 
    https://www.fakeaddress.org/about-us/oy-provider-list

example two: 
    https://www.fakeaddress.org/publications-resources

example three: 
     https://www.fakeaddress.org/consumers-families/early-start

How does one preserve those urls especially if you move hosting and website?

It's been a while since I've really thought about technical issues, so would really appreciate help on what I'm not thinking through on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to approach this issue would be to migrate the domain to the new hosting hence keeping the original URL, this is done by DNS configuration that is specific to your hosting server or partner.

<strike>If you give more details we could provide more specific solutions.</strike>

EDIT: Also if you mean to keep old URLs pointing to the new website, the 3xx redirects are the way to go, specifically 301 is meant for permanent redirects.

***UPDATE:***

Regarding your update, If you keep the same CMS and assuming the same domain and CMS configuration you don't need to redirect, but if you are using a new CMS most probably you will have a different URL scheme.
In this case you should probably go with 301 redirects, meaning when users access `https://www.fakeaddress.org/about-us/oy-provider-list` they will be redirected to something completely different, for example `https://www.fakeaddress.org/cms-specific-scheme/oy-provider-list?exampleparams=test`

Depending on the CMS you could also have some sort of configuration that actually uses the *same* URL scheme your previous system had, in this case you don't need URL redirects **BUT** you might struggle a little with technical configurations in the new CMS so it matches the URL scheme.

> we will be moving to a new platform for sure. So, assuming the unpredictability of the CMS of which we'll be moving to (any recommendations btw?) - the best way to assure of the same URLs is by using 301 redirects? Is there something I'm missing with this solution?

No, that is it! When your visitors access the usual links such as `https://www.fakeaddress.org/about-us/oy-provider-list` they will be redirected to the new address, since this is a permanent change redirect 301 will tell search engines this is correct and search engines will also assume the new addresses. This can be configured in your webserver (apache, IIS, etc.) using specific redirects or even using rule sets that could redirect URLs based on a pattern. IF you have a hosting partner it is best to contact them regarding the best configuration for the 301 redirects.

> but to clarify, 301 redirects can be applied to the same URLs, correct?

Yes, well what happens is when people try to access the old URL `https://www.fakeaddress.org/about-us/oy-provider-list` your new server will recognize this request and redirect it to the new address `https://www.fakeaddress.org/cms-specific-scheme/oy-provider-list?exampleparams=test`, in the end this new address is what people will be left with in the address bar BUT it is in fact the same page/information.

Comment: could you let me know what additional details would be helpful?

Comment: Give examples of how what is exactly meant by "preserving URL", are you transfering domain1.com to domain2.com?  something like OLD  --> NEW

Comment: I gave several examples of current URLs. I.e., we would like to keep our exact URLS as is while transferring to new platform, and hosting. Does that make sense?

Comment: we will be moving to a new platform for sure. So, assuming the unpredictability of the CMS of which we'll be moving to (any recommendations btw?) - the best way to assure of the same URLs is by using 301 redirects? Is there something I'm missing with this solution?

Comment: to clarify, the current platform we're on is not even a CMS per se, by rather some website hosting for "non-profits" type of situation, ie, they've got us locked in. Trying to figure out how to break out of it without their help with the exception of domain URL which should belong to us. Does this help?

Comment: unrelated to current question, but do you have a recommendation on duplicating content to move current content to new platform?

Comment: Will you be moving the main domain along with the website? so far I've been assuming so. What do you mean by duplicating content? Copying? Search engine index duplication?

Comment: to clarify, when you say "main domain", you mean our current URL, correct? If yes, I assume that our main domain is ours. My boss is not technical and would not know. But given that the name is ours, it should not be a problem dealing with the current host hopefully when getting our main domain. Sorry, what was the question?

Comment: I meant our entire website. Duplication of our entire website and its content. Our current host, I assume, would not be helpful, since they have us locked in. I'm assuming that the URL won't be a problem since that's a different sort of problem but content ... you know that's when they sort of got you. So, I need to recommend a non-technical tool that's not command-line (can't do that shit to save my life) that would duplicate/clone/what have you the content of the website, so when we move it to a new CMS (tbd), the content is there.

Comment: also, just read your edited answer, ie, the one you included my comment in - sorry if i'm being rather obtuse, but to clarify, 301 redirects can be applied to the same URLs, correct?

Comment: ie, say we manage to keep our domain name, but go to a CMS that has its own inane url scheme, be it underscore or dash, and we want to match link by link, so say our original link is: https://www.fakeaddress.org/publications-resources, and the new CMS does it like: https://www.fakeaddress.org/publications_resources, that's an applicable case for 301 redirect, correct? Sorry, I'll be quiet now.

Comment: Yes that is a correct case for 301 redirects.
Regarding duplicating the entire site, it really depends on what kind of contents  do you have on your site but if you can't retrieve the information from you previous provider that are a few programs that allow to create a "local copy" of the website but still I wouldn't trust those completely, if you want try this one https://www.httrack.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188744/discussion-between-jduartedj-and-user273072545345).